# How can I make image not to disappear in Laravel and keep already uploaded image?

Tags: php, laravel

I tried to solve by myself but couldn't manage, maybe you can help me:
When I try to update any post I should choose a new photo otherwise it disappears, how can I make it not to disappear and keep already uploaded image?

This is my code from PostController (using Laravel 8):

```
        $posts= Post::find($id);

        if($posts->photo === null) {
            $path = $request->file('photo')->store('images', 'public');
        } else {
            $path = $posts->photo;
        }

        $posts->update([
            'name' => $request->name,
            'body' => $request->body,
            'photo' => $path,
        ]);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

maybe you need something like this

```
$posts= Post::find($id);

    if($request->hasFile('photo') && $request('photo')->isValid()) {
        $path = $request->file('photo')->store('images', 'public');
    } else {
        $path = $posts->photo;
    }

    $posts->update([
        'name' => $request->name,
        'body' => $request->body,
        'photo' => $path,
    ]);
```